# Vitest + Emotion

Tags: reactjs, jest, vite, styled-components, react-testing-library

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании Vitest и Emotion в проекте с React + TS. Имеются тесты для компонента Select. Сам компонент стилизован через Emotion и после запуска тестов происходит вот такая ошибка.[image: Пример ошибки кода]

```html
import { Select } from "@shared/ui";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import { afterEach, beforeEach, describe, expect, test, vi } from "vitest";

describe("Select tests", () => {
  describe("value is string", () => {
    const testId = "dsaf-32fd-32rf-sdfa";
    const value = "das8gd87asdgsagd8gas8d";
    const onChangeValue = vi.fn();

    let select: HTMLDivElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
      render(
        <Select
          data-testid={testId}
          value={value}
          options={[
            { title: "Один", id: "das8gd87asdgsagd8gas8d" },
            { title: "Два", id: "dsgadgs8a8d7as8d87asg" },
          ]}
          setValue={onChangeValue}
        />
      );
      select = screen.getByTestId(testId);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      vi.clearAllMocks();
    });

    test("check default value", () => {
      expect(select.children).toBe(value);
    });
  });
});
```